# Como fazer resize de um form para a esquerda?

Tags: vb.net

Eu estava precisando mudar o tamanho de um `Form` sem bordas com o mouse, eu procurei algumas formas de fazer isso, mas todas elas quando o mouse saia do `Form`  o `resize` parava. Então eu resolvi fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Private Sub Panel3_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel3.MouseDown
    mbot = True
End Sub

Private Sub Panel3_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel3.MouseUp
    mbot = False
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If mbot Then                 
        Height += MousePosition.Y - Height - Top        
    End If

End Sub
```

Isso funcionou certinho, tanto para a direita, baixo e vértice(direita / baixo), mas eu não consegui fazer para cima e para a esquerda. Eu tentei de varias formas e a que mais deu certo foi essa:

```
  Dim pos = Width
    Dim loc = Left

    If mleft Then

        DesktopLocation = New Point(MousePosition.X, DesktopLocation.Y)
        Width = pos + loc - Left

    End If
```

Eu fiz com o que o `Form` mudasse de localização seguindo o cursor e a diferença da posição anterior e a nova fosse adicionado ao `Width`. O problema dela é que quando o `Form` é movido, o lado direito fica piscando.
Então o que eu queria saber é como eu posso "aumentar" o `Form` para a esquerda sem esse problema.